# SQLite auto increment starts with 0 and then the process is terminated

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, devart

I am trying to use SQLite in WinForms. So I created a table named `Artist` and it has 2 columns named `ArtistId`, `Name`. ArtistId's properties are: `INTEGER` `PRIMARY` `AUTOINCREMENT`.

In the foreach loop, if I give manually value, there is no problem.

```
    LtoSQLiteDataContext oc = new LtoSQLiteDataContext();
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var pdfs in articles)
    {
       var r = new PdfReader(pdfs);
       var title = r.Info["Title"].Trim();
       var m = new Artist
       {
                ArtistId = i,
                Name = title
        };
            oc.Artists.InsertOnSubmit(m);
            oc.SubmitChanges();
     i++;
     }
```

But if I ignore ArtistId like `//ArtistId = i;`, in the first record, `ArtistId` gets `0` and process is terminated. Here is screenshot:
[image]

I know in MySQL and MsSQL, auto increment field's value is never written. Because it gets number in the sequence.
I don't know, how auto increment poperty works correctly.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). And show the actual table creation statement.

Comment: I read from beginning to end, but I did not understand much. My native language is not English, may be it is orginated this. Maybe it really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the generated code for the ArtistId property looks like this (open the *.Designer.cs file):

```
[Column(Name = @"ArtistId ", Storage = "_ArtistId", CanBeNull = false, DbType = "INTEGER NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
   public long ArtistId 
   {...}
```

If not, please open your LinqConnect model and change the ArtistId property (open Properties for ArtistId property by double-clicking it):

- set Entity Key = True
- set Auto Generated Value = True
- save the model.

If this doesn't help, please [contact us](https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) with the test project (including LinqConnect model and test database file), so that we are able to investigate your scenario more clearly and find the solution for you in a shortest time.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late thank.I have just taken care of this problem. Thank you very much.